# VLC player cannot play network stream from the vlcj StreamHttp sample application

Tags: http, video-streaming, rtsp, vlc, vlcj

When I run the sample code in JAVA I get the following message-

```
Streaming 'F:\Video\Don.mp4' to ':sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://@127.0.0.1:5555/demo}'
       _       _
__   _| | ___ (_)
\ \ / / |/ __|| |
 \ V /| | (__ | |
  \_/ |_|\___|/ | 2.1.0
            |__/  www.capricasoftware.co.uk

VLCJ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

VLCJ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with VLCJ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Copyright 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 Caprica Software Limited.

vlcj: (Info.java:66)                           | INFO  | vlcj: 2.1.0

vlcj: (Info.java:67)                           | INFO  | java: 1.6.0_26 Sun Microsystems Inc.

vlcj: (Info.java:68)                           | INFO  | java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6

vlcj: (Info.java:69)                           | INFO  | os: Windows 7 6.1 x86

vlcj: (LibVlcFactory.java:143)                 | INFO  | vlc: 2.0.1 Twoflower, changeset 2.0.1-0-gf432547

vlcj: (LibVlcFactory.java:144)                 | INFO  | libvlc: C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\libvlc.dll

[18587ed0] stream_out_rtp stream out: Consider passing --rtsp-host=IP on the command line instead.
```

What does the above statement - "stream_out_rtp stream out" ?
similar errors I get on trying to stream in http

Comment: Are you trying to create a RTP/RTSP server using VLCJ? Yes, it is possible but try to test your `:sout` command using VLC command line first via VLC media player. You can pass VLC option `--rtsp-host=127.0.0.1` in a options string array in VLCJ when you call its factory contructor `factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(options);`

Comment: I am passing it in options '        `String media = args[0];
        String options = formatRtspStream("127.0.0.1", 5555, "demo"); mediaPlayer.playMedia(media,
            options,
            ":no-sout-rtp-sap", 
            ":no-sout-standard-sap", 
            ":sout-all", 
            ":sout-keep"
        );`'

Comment: Pass the option string array in the factory instance, not in the media player instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mediaPlayer.playMedia("dshow://", 
                    ":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://@:5555/demo}",
                      ":no-sout-rtp-sap", 
                     ":no-sout-standard-sap", 
                      ":sout-all",
                      ":rtsp-caching=100",
                      ":sout-keep");
```

try this it works for me..